# How can I use superscript in axis labels which are created dynamically from a character vector in R?

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, superscript

I'm trying to make a script that will make one graph from each column of my dataset, using ggplot. I would like to have the **y labels dynamically sourced from a separate dataframe, so I cannot construct them manually for each graph by hand**. So far, so easy.

At the same time (and this is where the problem comes in), the **y axis labels need to include superscripts** - for example, "x10^9/l", with the "9" being the only superscript character. I tried using parse(), but it fails, saying that the "/" is unexpected.

In essence, the core script looks like this, with the source data being in the "data" dataframe and the y axis labels being in the "labels" dataframe, the whole thing being enclosed in a for() loop iterating through the columns of "data" by increasing "i":

```
ggplot(data, aes_string(x = colnames(data)[k], y = colnames(data)[i], color = "Category", group = "Patient")) +
    ggtitle(labels[which(labels$name==colnames(data)[i]),]$nice_name) +
    ylab(label = parse(text=labels[which(labels$name==colnames(data)[i]),]$label))
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to escape the `/` character with a \

Comment: Sadly, this still gives the following error: Error in parse(text = labels[which(labels$name == colnames(data)[i]),  : 
  <text>:1:7: unexpected input
1: x10^9*\

Comment: Why is there a `*` in your error message?

Comment: To only make the 9 as superscript? I thought I needed to do that... I think I made it work with "x10^9 /l", it somehow only superscripts the 9 and then omits the space. Turns out I have no idea how expressions like this work >.<

Comment: Can you please share the code you use to generate the label? I see you use `$label`, but I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: The $label specifies a column in the dataset "labels", which I imported from a prepared .csv file. I was now able to use the text "x10^9 /l" to produce what I want, but am now stuck on showing "%", which it seems the parse() function also treats as a special character. I tried prefacing the % with \, "\%", but it turns out that also doesn't work. I don't think I know how these things work.

Comment: Can you please show what the label should look like (e.g., use MS Word or something similar to create a mock-up). Then I could show and explain how the expression should look like. Alternatively, spend time and study `help("plotmath")`.